# Do you know a nice PHP hack to do inline conditional assignation?

Tags: php, javascript, operators

I really enjoy `||` operator in JavaScript, where we can do inline conditional assignation.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 42;
var test = a || b || 'default value';
console.log(test); // 42
```

This is clear to read, and don't take too many lines.

---

In PHP, this logical operator return booleans:

```
$a = 0;
$b = 42;
$test = $a || $b || 'default value';
print_r($test); // bool(true)
```

Of course, we can do inline assignation using [ternaries](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$test = $a ? $a : $b ? $b : 'default';
print_r($test); // int(42)
```

But this make code ambiguous, this is not *that* easy to read.

---

So here my question come:

> Do you know a nice PHP hack to do inline conditional assignation ?

Comment: If you don't care about side effects, you can write a simple function that does it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php use a switch or add brackets `$test = ($a ? $a : ($b ? $b : 'default'))`;

Comment: @BassJobsen, He doesn't want to use ternaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.3+ [you can do this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$test = $a ?: ($b ?: 'default value');
```

Comment: @Don Because you don't repeat the operands. It has the same readability as `a || b || c`, just with added parentheses.

Comment: you have a point, but to me this is still "difficult to read" :) (difficult to read as you can consider difficult ternaries)

Comment: @deceze, there is no need for the parenthesis. This solution is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ninsuo Hmm, the parens are certainly necessary for the traditional ternary operator. Does it really work unambiguously without? If so, great! :D

Comment: As ternaries, this is not mandatory (but in ternaries, without parenthesis that's just head killer)

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as you don't need to short-circuit side effects:

```
function either_or() {
    $nargs = func_num_args();
    if ($nargs == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $args = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nargs-1; $i++) {
        if ($args[$i]) {
            return $args[$i];
        }
    }
    return $args[$nargs-1];
}

$test = either_or($a, $b, "Default value");
```

Comment: I agree that 0 or '' isn't `false`, this question (and the accepted answer) should be used carefully.

Comment: @Ninsuo `0` and `''` *are* `false`. At least according to PHP. Work with what the language dictates, only change the language's definition of "`false`" where necessary. :)

Comment: You wants something analogous to the Javascript expression, and it treats `0` and `''` as false. I briefly had a version of this function that just checked for `false` or `null`, but decided it wouldn't be equivalent to the JS or the ternary that he's replacing.

Comment: @deceze, yes of course it is, and that's the *side effects* Barmar  pointed out. Wrongly used, ternary shortcut may lead to unexpected (or at least undesired) behaviours.

Comment: deceze's comments have nothing to do with side effects. What I meant is you can't do `either_or(true, $b/0)` because the division by zero will happen before the call. But `true || $b/0` is safe because of short circuiting.

Comment: @Ninsuo No, the side effects he talks about is `$a || foo()` vs. `either_or($a, foo())`, if `foo` has *side effects* (modifies global state).

Comment: Ok, we were speaking of 2 different things then, my mistake.